# useContext inside axios interceptor

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-context

I cant figure out why my useContext is not being called in this function:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { MyContext } from "../contexts/MyContext.js";
import axios from "axios";

const baseURL = "...";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  timeout: 5000,
.
.
.
});
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  async (error) => {
    const { setUser } = useContext(MyContext);
    console.log("anything after this line is not running!!!!");
    setUser(null)

.
.
.
```

My goal is to use an interceptor to check if the token is live and if its not clear the user and do the login. I'm using the same context in my other react components. And its working fine there, its just not running here! any idea whats I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are not importing React nor useContext

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to put that line. Its already in the file. despite that still no success!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same issue as you. Here is how I solved it:

You can only use `useContext` inside a functional component which is why you can't execute `setUser` inside your axios interceptors.

What you can do though is to create a separate file called `AxiosErrorHandler`:

```js
// AxiosErrorHandler.js

import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const AxiosErrorHandler = ({ children }) => {
    const { setUser } = useContext(MyContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        const responseInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(response => response, async (error) => {
            setUser(null)
        })

        return () => {
            axios.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
        }
    }, [setUser])

    return children
}

export default AxiosErrorHandler
```

And then add `WithAxios` after `MyContext.Provider` to get access to your context like this for example:

```js
// App.js

const App = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(initialState)

    return (
        <MyContext.Provider value={{ setUser }}>
            <AxiosErrorHandler>
                {/* render the rest of your components here  */}
            </AxiosErrorHandler>
        </MyContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: it works great. Thanks for your time and info.

Comment: Hi how will you access error object here, if i try to use error.response.status it is giving me undefined

Comment: Hey Masood. I don't have any issues catching the errors in this schema. are you catching them in the axios interceptor? here how I modified it:
```

Comment: I'm having troubles using the context in the interceptor file, but with a state string property (e.g. access_token). If I try to get the access_token from my context, it's always null. Using a context method (signIn / signOut), I have no problem... Does anyone know why?

Comment: why using useMemo and not useEffect?

Comment: @SyedSaeedulHassanAli you can use either in this case

Comment: it should definitely be useEffect w/ and it should probably return a function that ejects the interceptor.

Comment: @Anatol Just a note according to docs (https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useMemo#parameters) function you pass to `useMemo` should be *pure*. Doing this in effect could be Ok, but then children's effects normally run earlier than parents IMHO.

Comment: this gives me a cryptic error:
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any issues catching the errors in this schema. are you catching them in the axios interceptor? here how I modified it:

```js
useMemo(() => {
    axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => response,
      async (error) => {
        const originalRequest = error.config;

        // Prevent infinite loops
        if (
          error.response.status === 401 &&
          originalRequest.url === // your auth url ***
        ) {
          handleLogout();
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
          error.response.status === 401 &&
          error.response.data.detail === "Token is invalid or expired"
        ) {
          handleLogout(); // a function to handle logout (house keeping ... ) 
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
        if (
          error.response.data.code === "token_not_valid" &&
          error.response.status === 401 &&
          error.response.statusText === "Unauthorized"
        ) {
          const refreshToken = // get the refresh token from where you store

          if (refreshToken && refreshToken !== "undefined") {
            const tokenParts = JSON.parse(atob(refreshToken.split(".")[1]));

            // exp date in token is expressed in seconds, while now() returns milliseconds:
            const now = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);

            if (tokenParts.exp > now) {
              try {
                const response = await axiosInstance.post(
                  "***your auth url****",
                  {
//your refresh parameters
                    refresh: refreshToken,
                  }
                );
                
// some internal stuff here ***

                return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
              } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
                handleLogout();
              }
            } else {
              console.log("Refresh token is expired", tokenParts.exp, now);
              handleLogout();
            }
          } else {
            console.log("Refresh token not available.");
            handleLogout();
          }
        }

        // specific error handling done elsewhere
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
  }, [setUser]);
```

Comment: Can you please show code of axiosInstance?

Answer (score 0):

I went with writing an axios provider, that is added below my other providers in my app entry.

Note: A `isInitialized` state might be needed for network request during app mounts to use the interceptors correctly.

```
interface AxiosProviderProps {
    children: ReactNode;
}

const AxiosProvider = ({ children }: AxiosProviderProps) => {
    // Hooks here
    const [isInitialized, setIsInitialized] = useState(false);
    const awesomeCallback = useAwesomeCustomHook()

    useEffect(() => {
        const responseInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
            (response) => {
                console.log("Response logic here");
                awesomeCallback("success");

                return response;
            },
            async (error) => {
                console.log("Error logic here");
                awesomeCallback("error");

                return error;
            },
        );

        setIsInitialized(true);

        return () => {
            axios.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
        };
    }, []);

    return isSet ? children : <></>;
};
```

Afterwards, wrap your application in the provider.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me. typescript type added.

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance, AxiosError } from 'axios';
import { NavigateFunction } from 'react-router-dom';

const createAxiosInstance = (navigate:NavigateFunction): AxiosInstance =>{
  const axiosInstance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_API_HOST,
  });
  axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response,
    (error: AxiosError) => {
      if (error.response?.status === 401) {
        navigate("/login")
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
  return axiosInstance;
}

export default createAxiosInstance;
```

in the calling component, pass useNavigate() as param to initialize an instance