# How to update api error into React Context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I need to handle the API errors globally in React, whenever there is an error in api , I need to add it to the context and subscribe in the Modal and show it in the Modal.
I have tried below, but it is not working since we should not use the **useConext()** outside react component.

I have gone through the below, not getting how I can use this for my scenario.

[stackoverflow - useContext inside axios interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296505/usecontext-inside-axios-interceptor#:%7E:text=import%20%7B%20useContext%20%7D%20from%20%22react,interceptors.)

```
// Context
const APIErrorContext = React.createContext({error:'',setError:(message)=>{}};

// App.js

const App = () => {  

    return (
        <APIErrorContext.Provider value={{ error:'',setError:()=>{} }}>
            <ChildComponent>
               
            </ChildComponent>
        </APIErrorContext.Provider>
    )
}

// Axios configuration
const apiClient = axios.create({baseURL:BASE_URL});
apiClient.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  (error) => {
    // Update error in context
    const { setError } = useContext(APIErrorContext); // React not allows to update context outside of a react component
    setError(error);

    return Promise.reject(error); // Let the error propagate
  }
);
```

If we use a handler like below, what we have to pass as a dependency in the **useEffect**

```
const AxiosErrorHandler = ({ children }) => {
    const { setError } = useContext(APIErrorContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        const responseInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(response => response, async (error) => {
            setError(error.response.message)
       

        return () => {
            axios.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
        }
    }, [] <-- What we have to pass here as a dependency. 
)

    return children
}

export default AxiosErrorHandler;
```

Comment: first of all, do you use axios as your http client or fetch api? or something else? please enrich your question with these informations.

Comment: If you are open to use a library, you can use zustand as your state manager which is very very easy to use and is able to update the state from outside of component

Comment: @Arashjahanbakhshan zustand documentation says there is an issue if we update the state out side react component, does this cause any issue?
https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/event-handler-in-pre-react-18

Comment: @kishore.jannarapu Looks like I missed that :D anyway, it's still usable. but that unstable function may have some bugs as the name suggests. you can use it at your own risk. if you encounter any issues, change the code :) another thing you can do is to create an event emitter; dispatch it in the Axios middleware and subscribe to it in the App component. whenever it is triggered, change the context value!

Comment: and please keep in mind, that it would be better if you could set the state inside of a component. maybe you can use react query or something that let you catch the errors inside of a component.

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate of the question you linked. [useContext inside axios interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296505/usecontext-inside-axios-interceptor). If you're having trouble with that implementation, [edit] your question to show what you tried and detail the problems you're encountering. _"Not getting it"_ is not a valid problem statement

Comment: Hi @phil, in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296505/usecontext-inside-axios-interceptor) there is a dependency *setUser* for useEffect.
In my case what I need to pass as dependency ? for every response I need check is there any error present or not and if there is an error then needs to update the context.